# Django update model instance asynchronously

Tags: python, html, django, asynchronous, celery

My website has a button to check notifications as a drop down while still remaining on the same page. I would like to update the field `unread` of every notification from `True`to `False` of that user when the button is clicked, without having to change or update the page.

I have been looking into Celery to solve this, but before digging to deep I would like to ask the community on what the best practice is to solve this type of functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the actual process of getting the notification does not take long you could just make it an ajax request. That would be the easiest way to do it.
You could also use Django channels and websockets on the front end but that is a bit more involved.
Just to add to that, Celery is more suitable for long running background tasks or scheduled tasks with beat.